# To POST value of GET by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, post, get

I need to POST a user name from a list of users that used GET from a server, but how to POST that user name as a string. 
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
  //get a list of users from server side
$.getJSON(
  '/userlist',
  function(data) {
    var user = data.users;
    $("#utbildning").text(user[1].username);
    $("#tekniker").text(user[2].username);
  }
);

//post user name and password at login  
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#knapp").click(function(){

    //name of the user should be a name from the user list comes from server
    var name=$.getJSON(
      '/userlist',
      function(data) {
        var user = data.users;
        user[1].username;
      }
    );
    var pass=$("#kod").val(); //password from input field
    var data = new Object();
    data["username"] = name;
    data["password"] = pass;

    $.ajax(
      {
         url: "/login",
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         processData: false,
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: 'application/json',
      }
    );
  });
})
```

Comment: is that how the code appears, or are you presenting sections?

Comment: the code presents GET and POST data managing

Comment: i mean, is that how it looks when you try to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple errors:

- Unless big changes you won't get anything using `var name = $.getJson(...`
- Then as $.getJSON is asynchronous, you should do whatever uses variable set from the ajax call in the $.getJSON callback method. as you do in your first call.

Here is a "corrected" version (well if your code is correct though):

```
  //get a list of users from server side
$.getJSON(
  '/userlist',
  function(data) {
    var user = data.users;
    $("#utbildning").text(user[1].username);
    $("#tekniker").text(user[2].username);
  }
);

//post user name and password at login  
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#knapp").click(function(){

    //name of the user should be a name from the user list comes from server
    $.getJSON(
      '/userlist',
      function(data) {
        var user = data.users;
        var name = user[1].username;
        var pass=$("#kod").val(); //password from input field
        var data = new Object();
        data["username"] = name;
        data["password"] = pass;

        $.ajax(
          {
             url: "/login",
             data: JSON.stringify(data),
             processData: false,
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: 'application/json',
          }
        );
      }
    );
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working perfectly. I did with another solution: if user[1] is chosen, it set the user's value to a invisible input field in html then post the input text to the server